# wsimport generating alphanumeric enum with underscore

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

While generating java classes from WSDL using wsimport Enum names are getting changed:

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlLocation>http://localhost/service/*</wsdlLocation>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <xdebug>true</xdebug>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <target>2.0</target>
                <keep>true</keep>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>PaymentCheck</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.pay.jaxws.paymentCheck</packageName>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/internal</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>PaymentCheck.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

WSDL Enum described as:

```
<schema> ....
<simpleType name="subFailureType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="SUCCESS"/>
      <enumeration value="FA01" />  <!-- Failure code for - Not enough cover -->
      <enumeration value="FA01" />  <!-- Failure code for - All other cases -->
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
    </schema>
```

Generated Class:

```
@XmlType(name = "subFailureType")
@XmlEnum
public enum SubFailureType {

    SUCCESS("SUCCESS"),
    @XmlEnumValue("FA01")
    FA_01("FA01"),
    @XmlEnumValue("FA02")
    FA_02("FA02");
    private final String value;

    SubFailureType(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static SubFailureType fromValue(String v) {
        for (SubFailureType c: SubFailureType.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

instead of Enum **FA01**/FA02 additional underscore **"FA_01"** is coming in the name.

Is there any way to correct this ? It's similar to the question [wsimport generating enum types incorrectly with extra underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731751/wsimport-generating-enum-types-incorrectly-with-extra-underscore) asked in 2012, not finding any workaround or solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve this issue using Bindings, In pom.xml added binding entry:

```
 <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.pay.jaxws.paymentCheck</packageName>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/internal</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>PaymentCheck.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                         <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/internal/paymentCheckBindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                    </configuration>
```

and added paymentCheckBinding.xjb as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings
    wsdlLocation="PaymentCheck.wsdl"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxws:bindings
        node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://account.ws.integration.payment.te.com/PaymentCheckWS']">

        <jaxb:bindings
            node="//xs:simpleType[@name='subFailureType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='FA01']">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="FA01" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        
    </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```